# A simple interest calculation programme in C always returns 0 as the result

Tags: c

I have tried both Turbo C and Borland C. No difference.
The programme is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int c,y;
    float r,si;
    printf("Enter the value of c,y,r");
    scanf("%d%d%f",&c,&y,&r);
    si=c*y*r/100;
    printf("%f\n",si);
    getch();
}
```

When I compile and run this no matter whatever value I choose, the answer is always 0.
A quick reply will be highly appreciated.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2060a9f727efb5b5)

Comment: I guess the solution here is to use a compiler that doesn't suck?

Comment: As cHao alludes to, it's the compiler that's screwing you. The code functions fine with gcc (& I can't see why not, VS) User input of `2 3 4.5` produces the output `0.270000`. If you want a small download, get Code::Blocks with MinGW (~100MB). If you want a debugger that rocks, download Visual Studio Express (~700MB last time I grabbed it).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. If you use `if (scanf("%d%d%f", &c, &y, &r) != 3) { fprintf(stderr, "Oops: did not read three values\n"); return 1; }`, do you still get 0 or do you get an error message?  If so, the problem is with your data entry. If you don't get the error message, have you tried printing out each of `c`, `y` and `r`? One of the most elementary but most effective ways of debugging is to print out the values that your program just received. If the values aren't what you expect, then it saves you a lot of debugging time. (Always check your inputs!)

Comment: @Bibhu your program is running well http://ideone.com/ae2SNt

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know that the commas in the input make such a huge difference. The input without the commas work. My compilers work good then. This question has been resolved to the satisfaction. I am new to StackExchange and to C. Thank you for being here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your scanf statement
    scanf("%d%d%f",&c,&y,&r);
to 
    scanf("%d %d %f",&c,&y,&r);

Answer (score 8):

I just ran your program on g++. I think your just doing the input wrong.

```
arvvvs@UHome-K53E:~/Documents/StackOverflowHelp$ ./interest 
Enter the value of c,y,r1 2 3
0.060000
arvvvs@UHome-K53E:~/Documents/StackOverflowHelp$ ./interest 
Enter the value of c,y,r1, 2, 3
0.000000
```

(I did remove the conio.h and getch line.)

If you want to have input with commas,
change from:

```
scanf("%d%d%f",&c,&y,&r);
```

to:

```
scanf("%d, %d, %f",&c,&y,&r);
```

(Or, even better, test that the return value from `scanf()` is 3. If it is not, then there is a data entry problem.)

Comment: Nice diagnosis with the commas.  What would you recommend as a way of spotting that problem?

Comment: I didn't find anything wrong with the syntax, so when I figured it was probably something to do with the input- and was saw a non zero answer so I figured it was the commas.

Comment: @arvvvs Rookie mistake: not checking `scanf`'s return value.